# Can you leave mid mission DMC and keep my collectibles?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

As the title says. Can I leave a mission in the middle of it in DMC-Devil May Cry and keep all the collectibles I found or do I have to finish the mission to keep it?

Thanks in advance-Charkz

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to beat the level for the game to save everything you did on that level. You can die in the same level, and keep the collectables, but once you exit to main menu, it's reset.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing DmC for finding the remaining collectibles.
 When I find the remaining **lost souls** and **keys** I simply exit to the main menu.

All the collectibles I had found, stays on my profile.